# MIPS: transitioning from simulation to real device

Tags: mips

I am doubtful as to whether this question is on-topic for SO, but given the large MIPS community here, I thought I'd try posting here first.

I have been learning the MIPS architecture for a while now, with the help of the MARS simulator. I am now looking for an actual MIPS device to replace the simulator. Ideally, it would have a software interface that lets me see the register values and memory, like what MARS provides with its user:

[image]

Essentially, having this system would allow me to validate the results of MARS. I heard that ARM microcontrollers are very popular these days, but are such MIPS boards or devices still on the market today? Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: There's a MIPS powered smartphones https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/4ofdkv/state_of_mips_plus_some_statistics/ You can probably buy some used ones still.

Comment: @user1095108 Thanks - I am not too familiar with Android development, but I assume there would be Android debugger tools that can show the register and memory, right?

Comment: there are some MIPS tablets in 2011-2012 but I don't know if any one produces MIPS devices any more, except custom devices. In Android you can still write native code and debug via JNI

Comment: smartphones use `arm`, but many DSL/wifi routers use `mips`. What you probably want, is an "SDK board" (e.g. beaglebone, for `arm`). Just google "MIPS sdk board". You should be able to hook it up to a host system (e.g. x86) and have cross-development tools. The debugger will probably be `gdb` and you can use the `ddd` GUI front end. Sometimes, the SDK vendor also has some more elaborate ways.

Comment: @CraigEstey there are some x86 smartphones, too. And there are a few MIPS smartphones although not easy to find

Comment: If you do go to a real system, you'll need to insert instructions into the branch delay slots if you're not already using them. `mars` is _accurate_ if slow. So, what do you mean by "validate"?

Comment: boards are still widely available, because there are still a lot of people use it, for example [The $65 MIPS Development Board for IoT on Linux](https://www.linux.com/news/65-mips-development-board-iot-linux)